# Twitter Timeline Widget isn't working in Chrome 30

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twitter

I have some problems with the Twitter timeline widget on my page in Chrome version 30.
Basically it just don't show up. It's working fine in Firefox 24 and Safari 5.1.10.

I already read trough a lot of so called solutions but none of them seems to work.

Here's a quick codepen for you guys to work with:
http://cdpn.io/biehJ

Greetings

edit: Also, the widget isn't showing up in the Widgets Configuration on Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned trying a lot of other solutions, so this is probably old news but just in case: do you have the Chrome extension **Disconnect** installed? If so, try disabling it. I had a similar issue and this was the solution that worked for me.